# Problema con el operador Spread en Javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de armar una función que necesita retornar el mínimo absoluto de los valores dentro de los arrays que reciba por parámetro así que armó la función de a continuación.

```
   var arreglosTest1 = [21,9,34],
        arreglosTest2 = [9,8,13];

    function minimoAbsoluto(...arreglos){
        return Math.min(...arreglos);
    }
```

Se supone que si mando por parámetros los arrays que puse en las variables tendría que retornar “8”, pero me devuelve “NaN”. Alguno sufrió el mismo problema o sabe por qué retorna ese valor?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo agrege todos los valores en un mismo array busque el menor de valor y escribi este codigo:

```html
miarray = function(valor) {
    var minimum = Math.min(...valor);
    console.log(minimum);
}

miarray([9,8,13],[21,9,34]);
```

y el valor que me da es el

```
8
```

pero si tu quieres algo similar a lo que hacias podrias hacer algo asi:

podrias crear algo asi:

```js
miarray = function(valor) {
    var minimum = Math.min(...valor);
    console.log(minimum);
}
var array1 = [9,8,13];
var array2 = [21,9,34];
miarray(array1,array2);
```

si tienes alguna duda puedes comentar.

todo el codigo lo ejecute online desde :[jsbin](http://jsbin.com)

**Actualizacion**
podrias usar  la funcion concat() de js para unir los array y asi buscar en los dos array el menor de esta manera:

```js
miarray = function(valor) {
    var minimum = Math.min(...valor);
    console.log(minimum);
}
var array1 = [9,8,13];
var array2 = [21,9,34];
miarray(array2.concat(array1));
```

[concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat)

Comment: Lo que veo en ese código es que te devuelve "8" porque el array que contiene ese valor es el primero que le pasas a la función, cambie el orden y me devuelve "9", que no es el valor más bajo de los 2 arrays.

Comment: podrias usar la funcion  concat() de JS para unir dos array asi buscar en los dos cual es el menor.

Comment: Listo, pero modifique un poco, al no saber cual es la cantidad de arrays que podrían llegar por parámetros cree un ciclo for y ahi use concat para luego encontrar el mínimo. De todas formas me sirvió el ejemplo que pusiste. gracias!

Comment: okay espero que te sirva la explicacion que te di

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos conceptos en juego aquí, el primero es ["rest params"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/parametros_rest)

```
function minimoAbsoluto(...arreglos) {
```

el uso de "`...arreglos`" hace que todos los parámetros que aún no tengan nombre/variable asignado se junten en un array "`arreglos`", si querés nombrar el primer parámetro y agrupar el resto:

```
function minimoAbsoluto( a, ...arreglos) {
```

Tomaría el primer parametro en "`a`" y el resto en un array "`arreglos`"

---

Segundo concepto ["spread syntax"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread)

```
    return Math.min(...arreglos);
```

En este caso el uso de "`...arreglos`" desparrama los elementos de "arreglos" separados por comas. Debido a que en el primer "`...arreglos`" (rest params) juntaste varios arrays en uno, al desparramarlos siguen siendo arrays separados por comas.

```
var arreglosTest1 = [21, 9, 34],
  arreglosTest2 = [9, 8, 13];

function minimoAbsoluto(...arreglos) {
  console.log("arreglos=", arreglos); 
  console.log("...arreglos=", ...arreglos); 

  b = Math.min(...arreglos);
  return b;
}

a = minimoAbsoluto(arreglosTest1, arreglosTest2);

console.log("a=", a);
```

Resultado

```
arreglos= 
[[21,9,34],[9,8,13]]

...arreglos= 
[21,9,34] 
[9,8,13]

a= 
NaN
```

Es decir que `b = Math.min(...arreglos);` está siendo equivalente a `b = Math.min([21,9,34],[9,8,13]);` lo cual da `NaN`.

---

Para concatenar los arrays (y luego poder usar el spread para el `Math.min`) hay varias formas una es con [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

```js
var arreglosTest1 = [21, 9, 34],
  arreglosTest2 = [9, 8, 13];

function minimoAbsoluto(...arreglos) {
  var c = arreglos.reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, ...val]);
  console.log(c);
  var b = Math.min(...c);
  return b;
}

a = minimoAbsoluto(arreglosTest1, arreglosTest2);

console.log("a=", a);
```

Otra opción es [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat)

```js
var arreglosTest1 = [21, 9, 34],
  arreglosTest2 = [9, 8, 13];

function minimoAbsoluto(...arreglos) {
  var c = [].concat(...arreglos);
  console.log(c);
  var b = Math.min(...c);
  return b;
}

a = minimoAbsoluto(arreglosTest1, arreglosTest2);

console.log("a=", a);
```

Otra opción, que incluso elimina duplicados es usando [sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set)

```js
var arreglosTest1 = [21, 9, 34],
  arreglosTest2 = [9, 8, 13];

function minimoAbsoluto(...arreglos) {
  var c = [ ...new Set( [].concat(...arreglos) ) ];
  console.log(c);
  var b = Math.min(...c);
  return b;
}

a = minimoAbsoluto(arreglosTest1, arreglosTest2);

console.log("a=", a);
```