# ¿Una función en Javascript que reciba N variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

***¡Hola! Mi código devuelve el cuadrado de cada numero que sea entero y positivo de un array. Si el numero no es entero ni negativo entonces la respuesta sera "No admitido. Necesito obtener le mismo resultado sin utilizar arrays y  debo hacerlo con una función que reciba N variables.***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cuadrado= [-9 , 5 , 8 , 3.7];

   cuadrado.forEach(function(elemento){

        if (Number.isInteger(elemento) && (Math.sign(elemento)==1)){
            var resultado = Math.pow(elemento,2);
            console.log(resultado);


        }
        else{
            console.log("No admitido");
        }

    })
```

Comment: No se puede poner n de parámetros en una función por que eso ya esta predeterminado solo y con un array.

Comment: @FernandoGameYt pensé lo mismo pero mi profesor dice que si se puede y según el es algo sencillo, ya he hecho de todo y no sé como hacerlo sin un array por eso acudí a esta comunidad.

Comment: Bueno pues preguntarle por que si buscas en internet no hay ninguna documentación eso yo creo que solo se puede con arrays.

Comment: ¡Claro que si chicos! solo que desconocéis su nombre, se llama "Operador de Propagación" o "Spread Operator" en inglés y existe cantidad de documentación al respecto para este y otros muchos casos de uso

Comment: Por supuesto que se puede tal como dice @dperezv.com, con el `Espread Operator`  Y no es nada nuevo, ya que viene con la sintaxis de **ES6, sintaxis que ya no se le puede considerar nueva** y que es bueno se vaya adapatando todos nuestros nuevos códigos a ésta.

Comment: en este contexto valdría mas hablar de `rest params, `spread = desparrama , rest = rejunta, ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183022/81450

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como práctica está bien, sin embargo pienso que se podría mejorar de la siguiente manera:

1. Nunca uses toda una librería sólo por unas cuentas líneas que al final ni siquiera te haran ahorrar código; **si**, hablo de **`JQuery`**; esto se puede hacer perfectamente con `javascript vanilla` y con menos líneas.
2. Siempre que puedas, usa funciones flecha `() => {}`, ya que te hace escribir menos código y además, hace el código mas legible.
3. Para condicionales como el de este ejemplo o ejercicio, trata de usar `Operador ternario`  **`condicion ? true : false`**, ya que, de igual manera que el punto anterior, te ahorra código ayudando a una mejor legibilidad.
4. Cuando sean funciones operacionales como en este ejemplo, no uses directamente `impresiones en pantalla` (ni llames elementos del `DOM`directamente) ya que la idea de estas funciones es que arrojen sólo un resultado, el que imagino luego será usado para alguna otra acción o incluso para el `DOM`.

*- Aquí un ejemplo con las observaciones que hice y Sin [JQuery].*

*- Dejé también las impresiones en pantalla tal como las tenías para que entiendas bien los cambios.*

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
   // Funcion cuadrado
   function cuadrado(...args) {
      args.forEach(el => Number.isInteger(el) && Math.sign(el) == 1
                        ? console.log(Math.pow(el, 2))
                        : console.log('No Admitido')
      );
   } // Fin de la función

   // prueba 1 ----------------------------
   // Por argumentos
   cuadrado(-9 , 5 , 8 , 3.7);

   // prueba 2 ----------------------------
   // Contenidos en un array
   cuadrado([-9 , 5 , 8 , 3.7]);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

¡Bienvenida a stackoverflow!

**Aquí tienes una posible respuesta**:

> Para todos aquellos que necesiten algo de **documentación** sobre el
>   **Operador de Propagación (`...`)** y sus posibles usos en javascript aquí podeis consultar la documentación de MDN
>
> [MDN: Operador de propagación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Funcion cuadrado
  function cuadrado(...args) {

    args.forEach(function(elemento){
      if (Number.isInteger(elemento) && (Math.sign(elemento)==1)){
          var resultado = Math.pow(elemento,2);
          console.log(resultado);
      }
      else{
          console.log("No admitido");
      }
    });
  }

  // Por argumentos
  cuadrado(8);
  cuadrado(8, -9, 5);
  cuadrado(-9 , 5 , 8 , 3.7);
  // Contenidos en un array
  cuadrado([-9 , 5 , 8 , 3.7]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```